# Nginx Reverse Proxy Golang Gorilla Websocket failing

Tags: go, nginx, websocket, nginx-reverse-proxy, gorilla

I am trying to reverse proxy my golang component which is using golang gorilla websocket. I am able to connect from client but getting immediately disconnected.

Nginx Config is tried in below way:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://internalexample.com:8000;
    }
}
```

Comment: More details are needed. It could be a problem with the server code, the client code or the nginx configuration.

Comment: Details like the exact output of arequest made with curl -v .  Are you happy with the value of proxy_pass?